# what do i have to do that google lists my events?

Tags: seo

Does anyone have informations about what are the expectations of google to list the events of my database/website like they if you search in google for "events berlin"?

The search result looks like [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=de&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=events%20berlin&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=dcadf66810dc146b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1357&bih=686).

```
Events Berlin, Events Berlin - veranstaltungen.meinestadt.de
veranstaltungen.meinestadt.de/berlinTeilenVeranstaltungen in Berlin: Veranstaltungskalender mit Konzerten ...

Di., 31. Jul    Invasion der Krebse
Di., 31. Jul    "Tuet auf die Pforten" Die Neue Synagoge 1...
Di., 31. Jul    Rudi Dutschke und sein Umfeld im Hanf Muse...
```

There are also direct links to each event.

Answer (score 1):

It's called microformats. You can find the events microformat at [schema.org](http://schema.org/Event). Keep in mind that using it does not guarantee Google will show the events in their search results.

Comment: 1st time i hear about that. Thank you very much :)